# Setting Mongoose collection name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm wrecking my head with this. I want to pass a collection name to the model constructor for an instance of Mongoose Schema object.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let schema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String}
}, { collection: 'testing' });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", schema);
```

I can change it from items to testing by using the collection parameter as indicated above. I have also tried setting a property via a method on the object. It sets it correctly as seen in a pre-save hook. But the instance still uses the original collection name. I want to pass in a collection name from the calling code.

```
let schema = require(path.join(__rel__, __models__, "schema"));
let item = new schema(itemObject);
    item.save(function(err, item) {});
```

I want some way of passing in a new collection name for that object to be stored in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the schema to be:

```
module.exports = function(collectionName) {
    return mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema, collectionName);
};
```

and call it like:

```
Item = require(path.join(__rel__, __models__, "ItemSchema")) 
("the_collection_name")
```

which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I declared schema like below

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const marksSchema = new Schema({
      username: String,
      year: Number,
      section: String,
      week: Number,
      marks: [{
        qid: String,
        questionName: String,
        marksScored: Number,
        isAttempted: Boolean
      }],
      quizmarks:Number,
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('marks', marksSchema, 'marks');
```

and reffered it as below in server.js

```
const Marks = require('../models/Marks');
```

models is the folder that contains all my schemas and it is a directory out of my server.js